# Create an admin page from template

Tags: 7

I want to create a completely bespoke admin page for some custom functionality. I don't want to hack the concept into render arrays as it will get messy fast.

I've got a menu declaration with a callback function, in here I can include and render templates. Using buffer streams, however, this only renders the file i'm passing.

Is it possible and if so how, to extend Drupal's default admin layout (header/footer/scripts/css) and print my 'template' in where `$page` would normally go?

I know I could view source and copy the code required, but I feel that would be an awful approach so please don't suggest.

---

Attempted solution not working.

```
function MYMODULENAME_menu() {
    $items = array (
        'admin/content/xxx' => array(
            'title' => 'xxx',
            'page callback' => 'MYMODULENAME_timetable_admin',
            'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        )
    );

    return $items;
}


function xxx_theme() {
  return array(
    'funky_admin_page_content' => array(
      'variables' => array(),
    ),
  );
}

function xxx_funky_admin_page_content() {
    echo "hello world";
  return 'hello world';
}


function MYMODULENAME_timetable_admin() {
  return array(
    '#theme' => 'xxx',
  );
}
```

Hello world isn't found in view-source. So I can only gather that the function isn't firing. I've cleared caches several times. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, it's quite straightforward.

You'll need a path for the page:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['admin/foo/bar'] = [
    'title' => 'Foo',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_admin_page_callback',
    'access arguments' => ['whatever makes sense'],
  ];

  return $items;
}
```

A theme declaration:

```
function MYMODULE_theme() {
  return [
    'funky_admin_page_content' => [
      'variables' => [],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Your function to build/get the content. Note that you could also put this in a template file, see [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7.x) for more details.

```
function theme_funky_admin_page_content() {
  // Build your HTML, return it as a string.
}
```

And your page callback:

```
function MYMODULE_admin_page_callback() {
  return [
    '#theme' => 'funky_admin_page_content',
  ];
}
```

Comment: I've added an edit to the post, I tried your solution. Whilst it worked in part. I have the header/footer with a custom title. I can't get my content function working. Any ideas?

Comment: Id' say the only problem is the last function, should be `'#theme' => 'funky_admin_page_content'`

Comment: Matched code like for like, its still ignoring the `function funky_admin_page_content`

Comment: What do you mean by "ignoring"? How are you confirming it's not being run? Did you make sure the module is installed and clear Drupal's caches?

Comment: I've tried `var_dump`, and `die` inside inside the function `theme_funky_admin_page_content` many times. Yes the module is 100% insalled, and i've cleared the cache about 25 times whilst trying multiple naming conventions.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you, sorry. The above works fine for me, I just copy/pasted it into a local site and added `return 'test';` to `theme_funky_admin_page_content`. As expected, /admin/foo/bar displays the admin theme with a single word "test" in the content

Comment: I've split it all out into a new module and it works. Thanks for your help. Can't tell you what the problem was prior.